# Show image of 10000x8000 pixels in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to show image in my iOS APP.The image is of 10000x8000, which is much higher than iPhone's screen resolution, if I add it to UIImageView ,the APP will receive memory warnings and lead to crash.Can any one give me a advice about how to deal with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you will have to implement some sort of tiling and break the image into smaller pieces, sort of like how google maps doesnt load the whole map at once

Comment: Thanks for advising~ That might be a  lot of work. Is it the only way?@Fonix

Comment: i dont but i guess Amit Tandel has a solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sample app from apple which displays large size image, it uses TileImageView scale the image and reuse tiles according to present zoom.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html

Or if you simple want scale down the image, you could use this.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.You've really been a big help! @Amit Tandel

Answer (score 0):

<sup>This is just a side note and not an answer.</sup>

@AmitTandel's answer will surely help you but,

**remember**, you should not always request for this high resolution image instead you should implement a logic which stores this high resolution image to somewhere after reducing it using @Amit's answer. And then at the time of re-requesting for the same image url, you should first look up in to your stored directory, if that image not exist only then you may request for an image.

But yes, I'm not suggesting you to follow my answer as you will require to download this very high resolution sized image (which is actually none of use), so if you're getting this image from your server, you can ask them to give you reduced size for images. I've heard that, they can reduce images to different sizes to help apps showing specific images at variant places.

Comment: The big pic is in local bundle. PM wishes  to zoom into the image to see the pixels more clearly, that  I have  to  show a big pic in its real resolution...Do u have some other adivices to meet this wired  requirement?  :)

Comment: You can try adding down grade image and then re-check with your PM for final assurance. I believe, it would work with the reduced size image as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, PM rejected the suggestion before. :(